# Failed to create a new virtual machine: VERR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: virtualbox, 15.10, virtualization

I want to set up a VirtualBox VM with Windows, but I get this message when I try to allocate disk space for virtual storage. How can I fix it?

```
Failed to create the hard disk storage /home/user/VirtualBox VMs/windows/windows.vhd.

Could not create the medium storage unit '/home/user/VirtualBox VMs/windows/windows.vhd'.

VHD: cannot set the file size for '/home/user/VirtualBox VMs/windows/windows.vhd' (VERR_INVALID_PARAMETER).

Result Code: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)
Component: MediumWrap
Interface: IMedium {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda}
```

I have VirtualBox VM 5.1.6 and Ubuntu 15.10. Earlier I had 5.0 installed, but I've removed it with

```
sudo apt remove virtualbox virtualbox-5.0 virtualbox-4.*
```

So I guess it ain't a case of version conflict or something like this.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the command that you used please?